# Mysql query select matched record plus record having same cid of the matched record

Tags: mysql

Table Schema

```
create table info(id integer, location_id integer, amount varchar(100), cid varchar(100));

INSERT INTO info
  (id, location_id, amount, cid)
VALUES
  ('1', '2', '5000', '1360'),
  ('2', '2', '3000', '2121'),
  ('3', '2', '2000', '1360'),
  ('4', '2', '1000', '2772'),
  ('5', '2', '3500', '1360');

create table users (
  userid integer,
  type varchar(18),
  accnum varchar(8),
  name varchar(28)
);

INSERT INTO users
  (userid, type, accnum, name)
VALUES
  ('1', 'patient', '8769', 'Ron K'),
  ('1', 'guarantor', '444321', 'Jhon W'),
  ('2', 'patient', '76890', 'Frank'),
  ('2', 'guarantor', '55543', 'Joe'),
  ('3', 'patient', '65438', 'Grace'),
  ('3', 'guarantor', '33332', 'bilbo'),
  ('4', 'patient', '89786', 'Sam'),
  ('4', 'guarantor', '432432', 'Susan'),
  ('5', 'patient', '90871', 'Subir'),
  ('5', 'guarantor', '555333', 'Sumit');
```

"Info" => id can have two record in user table based on type (patient, guarantor).
Now, i need to fetch all record which matches the accnum field also records those are sharing the same "cid" value of that matched record.

current query ::

```
SELECT
    guarantor.accnum as guarantorId,
    patient.name AS patientName,
    guarantor.name AS guarantorName,
    patient.accnum as patientAccountNumber,
    ob.amount,
    ob.id,
    ob.cid AS cid
    FROM info AS ob
    LEFT JOIN users AS patient ON (patient.userid = ob.id AND patient.type = 'patient')
    LEFT JOIN users AS guarantor ON (guarantor.userid = ob.id AND guarantor.type = 'guarantor')
    WHERE 
    1
    AND (
    patient.name LIKE "%8769%"
    OR patient.accnum LIKE "%8769%" 
    OR ob.cid LIKE "%8769%"
    ) 
    AND ob.location_id IN(2)
```

Current Result ::

```
guarantorId | guarantorName | patientName   | patientAccountNumber  | amount | id | cid
------------ --------------- --------------- ----------------------- -------- ---- ------
444321      | Jhon W        |   Ron K       |   8769                |  5000  | 1  | 1360
```

Expected Result ::

```
guarantorId | guarantorName | patientName   | patientAccountNumber  | amount | id | cid
------------ --------------- --------------- ----------------------- -------- ---- ------
444321      | Jhon W        |   Ron K       |   8769                |  5000  | 1  | 1360
33332       | bilbo        |    Grace       |   65438               |  2000  | 3  | 1360
555333      | sumit        |    subir       |   90871               |  3500  | 5  | 1360
```

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT guarantor.accnum as guarantorId,
>        guarantor.name AS guarantorName,
>        patient.name AS patientName,
>        patient.accnum as patientAccountNumber,
>        ob.amount,
>        ob.id,
>        ob.cid AS cid
> FROM info AS o
> JOIN users AS p ON (p.userid = o.id AND p.type = 'patient')
> JOIN info AS ob ON o.cid = ob.cid
> JOIN users AS patient ON (patient.userid = ob.id AND patient.type = 'patient')
> JOIN users AS guarantor ON (guarantor.userid = ob.id AND guarantor.type = 'guarantor')
> WHERE 1
>   AND (    p.name LIKE "%8769%"
>         OR p.accnum LIKE "%8769%" 
>         OR o.cid LIKE "%8769%" ) 
>   AND o.location_id IN(2);
> ```
>
> ```
> guarantorId | guarantorName | patientName | patientAccountNumber | amount | id | cid 
> :---------- | :------------ | :---------- | :------------------- | :----- | -: | :---
> 444321      | Jhon W        | Ron K       | 8769                 | 5000   |  1 | 1360
> 33332       | bilbo         | Grace       | 65438                | 2000   |  3 | 1360
> 555333      | Sumit         | Subir       | 90871                | 3500   |  5 | 1360
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5027ea99af1ff2e8089049f9b8b5a6b4)*

Comment: Working as expected... :)